# NSUserActivity and CoreSpotlight at the same time

Tags: ios, search, ios9, corespotlight

I'm planning to use both *NSUserActivity* and *CoreSpotlight* on my app at the same time, but somehow I can't make it work as I intended.

I'm currently working in a retailer online shop.

The following steps would be required:

**Step 1.** Every product the user visited in my iPhone app, will get identified by a NSUserActivity object which will be shown in Search API. Also, it's public and has a thumbnail image, title, description and expiry date.

**Step 2.** The user searches on the iPhone Search and the product does appear there. It will be also displayed within the app if the user taps on it. All easily achievable so far.

**Step 3.** The user has the right to 'save' that product, so nobody else can get it before he does. So, once the product is saved, I would like to modify the details of the NSUserActivity so it can show on the description the product is saved. As far as I know I can't do that, as there is no API to do that.

Ideally, I would like to modify the description and the image, to let the user know that product belongs to him now, so I would make the NSUserActivity private and I would modify its properties, but I can't find a way.

On the other hand, I could use NSUserActivity to handle the public products and CoreSpotlight the saved ones, but in that scenario, the app would display twice the same product. One that is the saved and private, and the one that is public. Something I would like to avoid, as I want you to see only once the same product, in this case, the one you have saved and is yours.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Consider adding what you've tried, what didn't work about it, etc.

Comment: What does `The user has the right to 'save' that product, so nobody else can get it before he does.` mean? Should that pull the public listing from the Apple index? I'm not sure the offer that ability currently.

Comment: Why can't you modify an activity? Isn't that their sole purpose, to generate results based on previous client side preformed actions. Just reindex the item in question. You should be indexing them according to some identifier, weather it be unique or domain. In some cases, you could simply delete it and then reindex. Either way, it's not too complicated which way you elect. If you can _retrieve__ the item, you already know how to identify it, so just rinse and repeat. As far as making it private, then your just going against the intent of the API. Sounds like your not sure what you want

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to prevent item duplication. All you need to do is specifying the same value in relatedUniqueIdentifier (NSUserActivity) and uniqueIdentifier (CSSearchableItem).
This will also increase your ranking.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CoreSpotlight_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016250) for details.